# Setting up Multisite on windows server with IIS7

Tags: installation

First off I'm not a server person. New windows box spun up, IIS7 was used to install one instance of Drupal 7. Great :)

However I need to have multiple sites running. I've read several tutorials on getting this to work, tried several solutions, and continue to gets errors (from page not found to "this drupal site is already set up"). Does anyone know if there are step by step instructions somewhere on exactly how to set up multisite on a windows box with IIS7?

The "base" drupal install is /inetpub/wwwroot/Drupal/DrupalTest/

Having very little knowledge of Windows servers is probably part of the issue. I really need basic step by step instructions and I have yet to locate any that assume you know essentially zero about windows. I've been taking notes so I can write some out if I eventually figure it out :)

One example I've followed: http://drupal.org/node/554336 : Yielded the "site already setup" when I tried to access the install.php from the second site.

---

I'm at the point where multisite would be nice, but if I need to use multiple instances of Drupal that's fine, I just need to be able to move forward with the content and be finished messing with the dang server, but I have no idea how to accomplish that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging, found out the combo of msSQL and PHP 5.3 caused the site to break. Reinstalled with PHP 5.4 and mySQL and it's running swimmingly!

Answer (score 0):

If any one still using IIS server to configure the multisite on drupal its pretty simple. 
First thing is make sure of two important files that need to be modified.
**sites.php
settings.php**

you don't need the local files (settings.local.php and sites.local.php) for multi site setup.

Configuring the above two files would be enough to setup the multi site on IIS.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-on-windows-using-iis

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can read more on how to install multisite in drupal 7 with below links.

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-windows/

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Plus this is with Apache